# Nginx is Slower than Apache downloading main.bundle.js

Tags: apache, nginx

I have an Angular2 app that I've been developing for a bit now.  Locally I run an Nginx server but the deployment server is using Apache.  To unify things I worked to move the deployment server to Nginx but I am getting extremely slow results with Nginx.

Apache loads in ~5 seconds (1.1MB transferred)
[image: Apache Loads in 5 seconds]

Nginx loads in 16-20 seconds (5MB transferred)
[image: Nginx loads in 20 seconds]

These are both on the same server pointing to the exact same directory. The actual size of main.bundle.js is 4470365 main.bundle.js so it seems Nginx is loading the entire file.

How is Apache able to download only 737K?

Comment: Is it gziped in both Apache && Nginx?

Comment: Nginx gzip module wasn't configured all the way.  It had `gzip on` but after completing the configuration according to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-the-gzip-module-to-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the features enabled in both the files with nginx and apache by clicking on the exact file in Inspect element Network Tab. Then go to Headers and then Response Headers as illustrated in the attached image.
[image: Headers contain the modules enabled on server]

Check if the gzip compression is enabled in any one of the server. That is the only reason for lesser file size.

Comment: that was it exactly.  Thank you.  I reviewed this blog (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-the-gzip-module-to-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) and enabled gzip on Nginx and all is right in the world.

Comment: No problem..and anyway glad you chose nginx over apache as under normal circumstances it would definitely perform better.